# Pygame Checkbox class works locally but not when imported

Tags: python, class, import, pygame

```
import pygame
from stuff_that_works import Square_checkbox
pygame.init()


class MyGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gamestate = 'intro_screen'
        self.run = True
        self.SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
        self.SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
        self.FPS = 30
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.SCREEN_WIDTH, self.SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('SM4')

    def options_Screen(self, event):
        self.screen.fill(defaults.BLACK)
        checkbox_1 = Square_checkbox(0, 0, self.screen, 30, 30, defaults.RED, defaults.WHITE, 'checkbox_1')
        checkbox_2 = Square_checkbox(40, 0, self.screen, 30, 30, defaults.RED, defaults.WHITE, 'checkbox_2')
        checkbox_3 = Square_checkbox(-100, -140, self.screen, 30, 30, defaults.RED, defaults.WHITE, 'checkbox_3')
        checkbox_4 = Square_checkbox(-100, -110, self.screen, 30, 30, defaults.RED, defaults.WHITE, 'checkbox_4')
        checkbox_5 = Square_checkbox(-100, -80, self.screen, 30, 30, defaults.RED, defaults.WHITE, 'checkbox_5')

        boxes = []
        boxes.append(checkbox_1)
        boxes.append(checkbox_2)

        for box in boxes:
            box.update_checkbox(event)
        for box in boxes:
            box.render_checkbox()

    def main(self):
        while self.run:
            self.clock.tick(self.FPS)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.run = False                    
                
                if self.gamestate == 'options':
                    self.options(event)
                elif self.gamestate == 'intro_screen':
                    self.intro_screen()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Edit1: As mentioned by Rabbid76 taking out the part that works and this adding the game loop.

I made a `Checkbox` class in pygame and it is working fine when run on the same file as the pygame loop, but doesn't work as intended when I import the class and create an instance.

The `self.active` is not being save or overwritten on the object.

I have tried to use @property with the same results.

Have also tried using `global active` but this changes all of the objects and not only the instance.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening to find a solution?

Comment: Why are you showing the `Square_checkbox` class? This code works fine. You need to show how `Square_checkbox` is used.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't occur to me that was more important!

Comment: The checkboxes are created anew in each frame. Therefore, all boxes always have the initial state. You must create the checkboxes once before the application loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Rabbid76 suggested it was because of the bad placement of an instance object.

Generating the checkbox outside of the loop worked.

Closing this, thanks!